# ¿Cómo y por qué me sale este mensaje utilizando JS y Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Estoy utilizando JavaScript y WordPress, y al dar clic en la flecha del carrusel o en el header me sale el siguiente mensaje. ¿Por qué me sale y cómo puedo solucionarlo? o podrian verlo en : 
wildroverhostels.com/wpt/arequipa/room/habitacion-de-prueba/

[image: Descripción 1]

[image: Pantallazo 2]

```
<div class="row" id="slider">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-principal">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="active item" data-slide-number="0">
                                <img src="<?php the_field('img_galery'); ?>"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="1">
                                <img alt="" src="<?php the_field('img_galery_dos'); ?>"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="2">
                                <img alt="" src="<?php the_field('img_galery_tres'); ?>"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="3">
                                <img alt="" src="<?php the_field('img_galery_cuatro'); ?>"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="4">
                                <img alt="" src="<?php the_field('img_galery_cinco'); ?>"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="5">
                                <img alt="" src="<?php the_field('img_galery_seis'); ?>"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="6">
                                <img alt="" src="<?php the_field('img_galery_siete'); ?>"/>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item" data-slide-number="7">
                                <img alt="" src="<?php the_field('img_galery_ocho'); ?>"/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Controls-->
                        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
                        </a>
                        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12" id="slider-thumbs"> 
                    <div id="Carousel" class="carousel slide">
                        <div class="carousel-inner">
                            <div class="item active">
                                <ul class="list-inline">
                                   <li>
                                      <a id="carousel-thumb-0" class="selected">
                                         <img src="<?php the_field('img_galery'); ?>"/>
                                      </a>
                                   </li>
                                   <li>
                                      <a id="carousel-thumb-1">
                                         <img alt="" src="<?php the_field('img_galery_dos'); ?>"/>
                                      </a>
                                   </li>
                                   <li>
                                      <a id="carousel-thumb-2">
                                         <img alt="" src="<?php the_field('img_galery_tres'); ?>"/>
                                      </a>
                                   </li>
                                   <li>
                                      <a id="carousel-thumb-3">
                                         <img alt="" src="<?php the_field('img_galery_cuatro'); ?>"/>
                                      </a>
                                   </li>
                                   <li>
                                      <a id="carousel-thumb-4">
                                         <img alt="" src="<?php the_field('img_galery_cinco'); ?>"/>
                                      </a>
                                   </li>
                                   <li>
                                      <a id="carousel-thumb-5">
                                         <img alt="" src="<?php the_field('img_galery_seis'); ?>"/>
                                      </a>
                                   </li>
                                   <li>
                                      <a id="carousel-thumb-6">
                                         <img alt="" src="<?php the_field('img_galery_siete'); ?>"/>
                                      </a>
                                   </li>
                                   <li>
                                      <a id="carousel-thumb-7">
                                         <img alt="" src="<?php the_field('img_galery_ocho'); ?>"/>
                                      </a>
                                   </li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                            <div class="item">
                                <div class="row">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
<script>
$('#myCarousel').carousel({
    interval: 2000
});

// This event fires immediately when the slide instance method is invoked.
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (e) {
    var id = $('.item.active').data('slide-number');

    // Added a statement to make sure the carousel loops correct
        if(e.direction == 'right'){
        id = parseInt(id) - 1;  
      if(id == -1) id = 7;
    } else{
        id = parseInt(id) + 1;
        if(id == $('[id^=carousel-thumb-]').length) id = 0;
    }

    $('[id^=carousel-thumb-]').removeClass('selected');
    $('[id=carousel-thumb-' + id + ']').addClass('selected');
});

// Thumb control
$('[id^=carousel-thumb-]').click( function(){
  var id_selector = $(this).attr("id");
  var id = id_selector.substr(id_selector.length -1);
  id = parseInt(id);
  $('#myCarousel').carousel(id);
  $('[id^=carousel-thumb-]').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
});
</script>
<!-- acordion -->
<script>
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#accordion" ).accordion( {
        heightStyle: "content",
        collapsible: true,
        active: true
        <?php
            if (wp_is_mobile()) { ?>
                ,active: true
                <?php
                    } ?>
                } );
                jQuery('#accordion h3').bind('click',function() {
                    var self = this;
                    // Altura delacordion
                    var accordion = jQuery("#accordion").offset();
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        // Numero de elemento
                        var element = jQuery(self).attr('data-element');
                        var scroll = accordion.top - 200 + (element * 90);
                        jQuery('body,html').animate({ scrollTop: scroll });
                    }, 310); // ensure the collapse animation is done
                });
            } );
</script>
```

Comment: Tiene pinta de que elementos "accionables" de la página que van a ser manejados usando JS, no están implementados, solo muestran un mensaje tipo alert. Tendrías que inspeccionar los elementos que generan los mensajes y ver en la consola de depuración JS que es lo que esta pasando si no hay un código directamente asociado.

Comment: Por favor, añade el código que tengas y no sólo pantallazos del resultado.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ese diálogo se muestra cuando hacés click en una etiqueta `<a>` cuyo atributo `href` comienza con `#`. Para solucionarlo buscá el script que está en `/wp-content/themes/edsbootstrap/assets/js/general.js` y borrá la línea 89 que dice: `alert('test');`.